# read data from clipboard correctly in r

Tags: r, import

I want to read data to r from clipboard but the data dimension is wrong. The question is **how I can read data from clipboard correctly** and **how can I distinguish the data separator**.

My data is this

```
group month Estimate lwr upr
placebo 0 18.7 17.6 19.9
placebo 6 21.5 20.3 22.7
placebo 12 24.3 22.8 25.7
placebo 18 27.0 25.2 28.9
active 0 18.7 17.6 19.9
active 6 20.8 19.6 22.0
active 12 22.9 21.4 24.3
active 18 25.0 23.1 26.8
```

Code I tried is this

```
d1 <- read.delim('clipboard')
d2 <- readClipboard()
```

Comment: Where is `readClipboard` from?

Comment: What about `readr::read_table("group month Estimate lwr upr
placebo 0 18.7 17.6 19.9
placebo 6 21.5 20.3 22.7
placebo 12 24.3 22.8 25.7
placebo 18 27.0 25.2 28.9
active 0 18.7 17.6 19.9
active 6 20.8 19.6 22.0
active 12 22.9 21.4 24.3
active 18 25.0 23.1 26.8")`

Comment: @VitaliAvagyan I think OP is trying to read data automatically from the clipboard; reading data manually through `read.table` seems like a back-to-front approach.

Comment: perhaps, `readr::read_delim(clipboard()," ")`

Comment: It works when I copy OP's table and run the above function.

Comment: @MauritsEvers  `readClipboard` was from `utils`

Comment: @VitaliAvagyan `readr::read_delim(clipboard()," ")` the code wroks well. Thanks a lot, but how can you know the separator is **space** not a **tab**.

Comment: I would suggest trying `data.table::fread` if they have a way to read from clipboard